# OpenSSL generates unknown Email addrress in csr file?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, openssl

I use OpenSSL on ubuntu to generate a CSR file that I will paste to the SSL certificate provider. when I paste the code, I see an unknown e-mail addreses to select but not the e-mail address I have entered during csr creation.
Where does OpenSSL get this email addresses, like postmaster@mydomain.com, admin@mydomain.com.

The command that I use is:
sudo openssl req -out csr.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout private.key

Comment: This question belongs to ServerFault as it doesn't fit into the scope of this Q&A site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that most Certificate Authorities ("certificate provider") ignore the e-mail address from the CSR itself, since it is user provided input and thus not trustworthy.

The e-mail addresses presented to you during the application process are

1. from the Admin-C WHOIS record of the domain for which you are applying a certificate for
2. some standard addresses which are assumed to usually exist for most domains (postmaster@, admin@, ..)

This is done by the CA to prevent fraud and ensure that only someone with access to the domain is able to buy a certificate for it.

You can't change that. You can:

- Either configure one of the presented e-mail addresses on your domain and fetch the confirmat e-mail from there
- Or, if possible, change your Admin-C records e-mail address (which will take a while)